# How to permanently redirect myforum.com/index.php to myforum.com

Tags: php, redirect, windows-server-2008, iis-7.5, forum

I am using MYBB php forum at windows server 2008 on IIS 7.5

I want to permanently redirect index.php to main url

How can i do that ?

Example

```
http://forum.monstermmorpg.com/index.php
```

Will be redirected to

```
http://forum.monstermmorpg.com
```

How can i do that ? Thank you.

The rewrite rules i am using

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^([^&amp;]*)&amp;(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://forum.monstermmorpg.com/{R:1}?{R:2}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^sitemap\-([^./]+)\.xml$" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="misc.php?google_seo_sitemap={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 3" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^Forum\-([^./]+)$" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="forumdisplay.php?google_seo_forum={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 4" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^Thread\-([^./]+)$" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="showthread.php?google_seo_thread={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 5" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^Announcement\-([^./]+)$" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="announcements.php?google_seo_announcement={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 6" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^User\-([^./]+)$" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="member.php?action=profile&amp;google_seo_user={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 7" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^Calendar\-([^./]+)$" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="calendar.php?google_seo_calendar={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 8" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^Event\-([^./]+)$" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="calendar.php?action=event&amp;google_seo_event={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your using a web.config file and have the IIS Rewrite Module installed, this rule should work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="CanonicalHostNameRule" stopProcessing="true">
                  <match url="^(\w*/)?index\.php" />
            <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="forum\.monstermmorpg\.com$" />
            </conditions>
                   <action type="Redirect" url="http://forum.monstermmorpg.com/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks working great though i did not add runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests because it might cause some problems.

Answer (score 0):

On index.php write something like this:

```
//> header 302
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']=='/index.php')
 header('Location: /');

//> header 301
header( 'HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently' );
header( 'Location: /' );
```

Comment: Even though this solution would work, wouldn't it be slightly better to do it using the IIS config file instead of PHP?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean. How is a search engine going to know whether the redirect was done by IIS or by PHP and why would they prefer one over the other? All they see are the response headers.

Comment: You are mistaken. They are able to understand whether redirect permanent or temporary by the headers. Your solution would be temporary 301.

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG: permanent? if you don't want to be permanent do a: `header("Location: /foo.php",TRUE,302);`

Comment: and @MonsterMMORPG: if you don't want a PHP solution next time don't add it as tag